# Can I see a list of votes for my comments?

Tags: support, comments, votes

Quite often, advice or recommendations are given as comments to questions and answers.  Maybe slightly off-topic, does not meet one of the requirements of the question, or to back up someone else's answer with a URL to more information, etc etc.

This may seem trivial, but like asking and answering questions - it's nice to keep track of where you've had positive input.

I know you can easily see a list of comments that you have left (Activity | Comments) but it does not list the votes for your comments.

Is there a display which includes the number of "Great comment votes" for each of my comments tucked away somewhere else?

Comment: Please note that http://data.stackexchange.com works on a data dump and is not live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a display which includes the number of "Great comment votes" for each of my comments tucked away somewhere else?

Not yet, but here's a query which displays all your comments with a link to the post in descending order of score. Since the query runs on the data dump - the results are a bit dated.

> http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/858/where-have-i-commented

Comment: Nearly really useful, but I see some of the vote scores are reallly out of date.  Still does the job though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will show you your comment score distribution - a query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer... perhaps write a query that brings up all of your comments and you can revisit them?

> http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution